# .htaccess - forcing https except for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, subdomain

I am currently using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it seems to work to load my main page via https, and my subdomain via http but ONLY in IE. It does not work in chrome or firefox.

When I had this setup:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It refused to load my subdomain at all.

Can somebody explain to me what the difference is between https = off, and https !=on? And what am I doing wrong that is preventing this from working in firefox and chrome?

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody explain to me what the difference is between https = off, and https !=on? And what am I doing wrong that is preventing this from working in firefox and chrome?

`%{HTTPS} = off` is *wrong*. Mod-rewrite isn't very clever about parsing its rules, so when it sees a space between `=` and `off`, it thinks that `off` are rewrite condition flags, which throws an error because that's not a valid flag. You don't really need the `=` or `!=` stuff:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

is good enough, and your first rules are also fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

are all the same.

The problem here isn't your rewrite rules, it's either how your server is configured with SSL or some browser settings (or you need to clear your cache).

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for that response! It definitely clarified a lot of issues I was having and I got it working thanks to you!